# Tension in string involved in multiple Atwood machines and how is it different in different situations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Consider the 2 situations shown in the figure

[image]

In **situation 2**, it's quite obvious that *T/2* is proportional to **g**. But, what I've come to know about situations like **situation 1**(here) is that- this tension *T/2* is now proportional to **(g-a)** (called as *effective g*). Now this thing has totally confused me, how does **situation 2** differ from **situation 1**? If I think of selecting the *2nd branch of string*(where tension is **T/2**) as a reference, then in both situations, the **effective g** should be **(g-a)** , isn't it? I know that I'm going horribly wrong somewhere, but can someone help me with this doubt? Can someone provide a detailed answer to help me out?

Comment: This might help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force

Comment: @Noah J. Standerson, do you want to say in situation 1 and situation 2, we take different frames of reference, and thus end up getting different results? But why do we take different frames of reference in both cases? Is there any such problem if we look at both situations from the same reference?

Comment: I'm familiar with fictitious forces, but what I don't get is why do we assume an inertial frame in situation 1 and a non-inertial frame in situation 2 to conclude the tension in string in respective situations.

Comment: Do you mean to make the masses on the right different in scenario 1?

Comment: Masses may or may not be different. The issue is that in the 1st situation, we have an atwood machine connected to the second leg of the string, whereas in the 2nd case, we have a normal mass attached to it. How are the two scenarios different from each other?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question correctly, you are worried about why is T proportional to g and not g-a in situation 2. If that is it, then let's work in the ground frame.
Assume m>m' , then the acceleration of the two blocks is 
                                a=((m-m')g)/(m+m')
Now, using Newton's second law on m', we have:
                                    T/2-m'g=m'a
But remember that a is proportional to g, hence T is proportional to g and not g(-/+)a, as the case may be.

Comment: Also, even in situation 1, a=g/3. So actually T is still proportional to g.

Comment: Yes, 'a' has to be a function of 'g'. But, in situation 1, we view the scenario from an inertial frame, and so we have to take into account the pseudo force. But we don't view it the same way in situation 2. Why is it so?

Comment: Wait, how can there be a pseudo force if you are in an inertial frame?

Comment: My bad, I'm really bad at typing. In situation 1, we view the scenario from a non-inertial frame(as if the pulley were in a lift accelerating downwards). Then why don't we do the same for the mass m in situation 2?

Comment: In case2, the pulley isn't accelerating, right? Do you want to view the system by sitting on one of the masses?

Comment: When we write down the equations involved, in situation 2, we would like to involve only the tension and the weight of the mass m in the second leg of string, and it would be going down with an acceleration. But, we can't write the same for situation 1, where we'd need to incorporate a pseudo force acting on second pulley system. I'm confused right here, can't we assume this second pulley system just like any other normal mass(as in situation 1)? Why does the fictitious force come up then?

Comment: If you do that, how would you describe the dynamics of the two masses attached to that pulley? If you consider that system to be just like the one in situation 2, having a mass 2m, then you still get that a=(2mg-mg)/3m, which is the same as what you will get if you consider the two masses individually. The only problem will be that now you have to describe the individual acceleration of the two blocks, and for that, you will have to consider them separately.

Comment: @AbhinavTahlani , So basically your question is why in first scenario,  we can take the two masses as one system  ?

Comment: @AbhinavTahlani  , If thats your question,  then there is a very simple explanation for it.

Comment: We can make the masses on the second pulley in scenario 1 equal to 2m , only if the Centre of Mass of the both the masses can be represented in one point (while falling) .  But while falling,  The C.O.M (of second pulley) is not coming down in the same rate as the "C.O.M " of the mass on the other side

Comment: So, instead of taking it as 2m and rather finding out the acceleration of the centre of mass of the 2 bodies concerned, can we approach it correctly?

Comment: There is no relative acceleration between the two blocks. So you can assume it to be a mass 2m entity (scenario 1).